# ajax post data and insert to database

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to insert comment using ajax. Everything works fine except the $_POST. It doesn't seem to post the data so the comment field in table is empty. Other things work fine, like inserting date. I only have problem with the ajax (no problems in php). 
Anyway, here is my code:-

```
<head>
<script>
function su_post(id) {
    $("#load_post").show(),

    $("#post_submit").click(function() {
    var c_post = $("#c_post").val();
    var dataString = '&c_post=' + c_post;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/script/post.php',
    data: "id=post_script" + id,
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
    $("#load_post").fadeOut();
    }
  })});
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form_post" method="post" action="javascript:su_post(1)">
<label for="c_post">Post your updates/status</label>
<input type="text" name="c_post" id="c_post" />
<br /><br /><input type="submit" id="post_submit" value="Post" />
</form>
</body>
```

edit: since you might  not have understood me; there is a problem in obtaining the value you type in the input box and posting or sending the value to post.php. When I put `data: {id: post_script + id, c_post: c_post}`, it the code doesn't seem to load the php file at all. (gets stuck on posting -> http://prntscr.com/10dmjt)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What is the role of your `rand` field? What happens if you leave it out? And why is the `append` statement commented out?

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to post that line. I had commented it out so I will remember it when I need it

Answer (score 0):

The data property in your `ajax()` function needs to be of Object type. Like this:

```
data: { id: "post_script" + id }
```

You also had some syntax errors, your function should look like this:

```
function su_post(id) {
    $("#load_post").show();

    $("#post_submit").click(function() {
        var c_post = $("#c_post").val();
        var dataString = '&c_post=' + c_post;

        $.post("ajax_login.php",{ user_name:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val(),rand:Math.random() });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/script/post.php',
            data: { id: "post_script" + id },
            cache: false,
            success: function(){
                $("#load_post").fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code was quite a mess. Also, have you included the jQuery library in your page?

Comment: Yes, I did include the jquery library

Comment: When I put data: {id: post_script + id, c_post: c_post}, it the code doesn't seem to load the php file at all. (gets stuck on posting -> http://prntscr.com/10dmjt)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function `javascript:su_post(1)`, so it would seem that your data field contains `{id: "post_script1"}` only. Where is your "comment" being passed to the AJAX? You don't do anything with the `var dataString` after assigning a value to it...

Maybe you intend to have something like this line:

```
data: "id=post_script" + id + dataString,
```

since, I think `dataString` contains `&c_post=whatever the comment is` after you did

```
var c_post = $("#c_post").val();
var dataString = '&c_post=' + c_post;
```

I do wonder whether you need some additional quoting in the `dataString` as well... I don't believe the `$(#c_post).val()` function takes care of it, so I suspect you need an `escape()` somewhere - or does the `ajax` do it for you? I guess that's where @errieman's `{}` comes in handy... it turns the entire thing into an object and takes case of the escaping for you. That would make the line you need:

```
data: {id: post_script + id, c_post: c_post}
```

I doubt any of this turns out to be exactly right, as I'm having to guess what you are trying to do - but I do hope one of these will give you inspiration to solve your problem.

Comment: I see from your comment to the other question that you tried implementing one of my suggestions. I suspect your php script isn't happy being passed an object, so try to just add (escaped) dataString as per my first suggestion; what does that do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have worked when I took out the statement `$("#post_submit").click(function()` and put var `c_post = $("#c_post").val();var dataString = '&c_post=' + c_post;` on the top.
Now my code looks like this :-

```
function su_post(id) {
    var c_post = $("#c_post").val();
    var dataString = '&c_post=' + c_post;
    $("#load_post").show(),

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/script/post.php',
    data: {c_post:c_post},
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
    $("#load_post").fadeOut();
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: I am glad my hunch that you were passing the wrong information (`id` instead of `c_post`) was helpful. You can remove the `dataString` line from your code now since you no longer use it...

Comment: what about var c_post = $("#c_post").val();?

Comment: You could move that into your `data:` statement too- no need for the intermediate storage. My rule: if you use a variable just once, keep it only to help readability. This is a marginal case for that rule...